# Convert button input type submit to link button

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have button `<input type ="submit">` that i want to convert into link button without affecting functionality. Issue is `name` attribute is used in existing functionality.

Below is the Button Example :

```
<input type="submit" id="b1" name="SEND" value="Send" class="f-special-button" onclick="DisableButton();">
```

Convert button to link which act same as this button..

Comment: what do you mean? do you have a fiddle or a picture or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a short JS:

```
<a name="SEND" href="javascript: submitform()">Text</a>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function submitform()
{
  document.form_name.submit();
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  to perform the action on button click like this

```
<form action="put the name of page you want to show here.html">
<input type="submit" id="b1" name="SEND" value="Send" class="f-special-button" onclick="DisableButton();">
</form>
```